# BASH - Linking 2 processes, terminate process 2 when process 1 is terminated

Tags: linux, bash

I have a process running, which is creating a file

```
clean_db () {
    while read i
      do
        Some_long_process >> output.txt

      done < input_db
```

I want the other process to run and counting the lines created, which works fine

```
 while true
do 
    wc -l output.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
    sleep 5
done
 }
```

But I can't manage to stop the second process when the first one ends,
looks like the second one continues working even if the first one is ending.
Hos to link the second one to the first one in terms to stop it when first is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the second function as a background sub-process, and then kill all the subprocess when exiting the shell script:

```sh
second_process () {
  while true
    do 
    wc -l output.txt
    sleep 1
    done
}


clean_db () {
  second_process &
  for i in $(seq 5);
      do
        echo "kfjdjkfdf" >> output.txt
    echo "Done adding" $i
    sleep 1
      done 
}

clean_db
pkill -P $$
```

Note that `pkill -P $$` kills all sub-processes.

Comment: The last one I guess would be better as this? :   clean_db &&
pkill -P $$

Comment: Also, an issue here is that, if killing process with CTRL+Del the background process keeps running

Comment: @Zaza `CTRL`+`Del` can kill processes? I didn't know about this. Which signal does `CTRL`+`Del` send to the process? BTW, it's not killing processes on my ZSH terminal. What is your terminal?

Comment: Sorry, spelling mistake:), I ment CTRL + C Not killing or stopping the process which is running in the background, let say you wish to stop the process for some reason, the main process stops but the process in the background keeps running, I'm using Putty and sometimes MTPuTTY client over CentOS.

Comment: @Zaza okay then you need to capture that signal (CTRL+C) in the script and allow it to gracefully exit, killing all subprocesses. You can search for it on Google, on how to capture signals in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

The final and complete solution is the following:

```
Check_process () {
 while true
do 
    wc -l output.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
    sleep 5
done
}

clean_db () {
# The following sets build in bash trap for Ctrl+C and kills background process when Ctrl+C is detected
trap 'kill $BGPID; exit' INT 
Check_process &
BGPID=$!

    while read i
      do
        Some_long_process >> output.txt

      done < input_db    
}

clean_db
```